# Xcode storyboard view on rotation

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard

I would like to have a view to the top or left of the device.
[image]

I have tried using a stack view to rotate the view but I was unable to use all interface orientations. 
Example: the iPad orientation has a regular width and height in both portrait and landscape orientation. Thus I believe I cannot rotate the stack view axis on this device.
What are other options to keep the view how I want it preferably using the storyboard with auto-layout only but if needed using swift code.

Edit:
To clarify, both the blue and grey view can be seen as empty `UIView` for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, when you rotate the device, you want the text, buttons, etc to rotate but the background to stay the same (as in the view takes up the same screen area, but things in the view are rotated), correct?

If so, use [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) to give your views different constraints for different views